# Material UI v1 table with scroll (overflow: scroll)

Tags: material-ui

How to create table with scroll overflow in Material UI v1 (v1-beta currently)? In component demos in MUI documentation there is no such example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In all of the Table examples, there is a class applied to the `div` containing the `Table` that configures horizontal scrolling. It isn't apparent unless you're viewing the documentation with a sufficiently small viewport. (see [BasicTable.js](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/docs/src/pages/demos/tables/BasicTable.js#L10)):

```
const styles = theme => ({
  paper: {
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    overflowX: 'auto',
  },
});
```

The `paper` class is applied to the root element:

```
function BasicTable(props) {
  const classes = props.classes;

  return (
    <Paper className={classes.paper}>
      <Table>
        ...
```

If you want a vertical scroll, you'll need to specify a height and include considerations for `overflow-y`.  If you want both horizontal and vertical scrolling, you can set `overflow` and both axes will be configured:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  paper: {
    height: 300,
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    overflow: 'auto',
  },
});
```

**Note:** This will not fix your column headings, because it is applied to the container.  This adjustment will apply scrollbars to the entire table - heading, body, footer, etc.

Comment: Ken Gregory, Is there any solution to keep the header in place while having the vertical scroll enabled for the body only?

Comment: mui has the stickheader, for ref: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/#sticky-header
Or you can try the css, position sticky

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the table header fixed and scroll just the table body I've come up with this solution.

First I added to each of the table components the `component="div"` property in order to get rid of the table skeleton completely.

Then I've added to `Table`, `TableHead`, `TableBody` and `TableCell` the `display: block` rule to override the material rules.

`TableRow`s will get `display: flex`.

`TableBody` will get the desired fixed `(max-)height`, plus `overflow: auto`.

Of course by using `div`s instead of table tags the header and body cells lose the table alignment. In my case I solved this by setting to the first cells a fixed `width`, same for the first cells in the header and the first cells in body (or you can go for percentages as well) plus a `flex-shrink: 0`.

The second cells got `flex-grow: 1`

[image: Preview of my table]

Note: [Material UI v1](https://v1-5-0.material-ui.com/) used

Comment: There's some detail [on github here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/6625#issuecomment-381729555) for fixing header rows using `position: "sticky"`

Answer (score -1):

Use the "stickyHeader" property on table such as `<Table stickyHeader>...</Table>`