# Fix table thead when scroll browser page in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to fix table thead in angular when it gets top page. When I scroll inside table scrolling thead is fixing and this situation I use sticky but when I scroll browser page it doesn't work. Bellow a image what exactly I want

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWAGj.jpg)

in html

```
 <div class="table-responsive " style="width: 100%; height: 670px;">
    <!--<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">-->
    <table class="table table-hover info">
        <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: lightskyblue;">
            <th>ID</th>
            <!--<th jhiTranslate="jhiApp.kassa.date_enter">DateEnter</th>-->
            <th jhiTranslate="jhiApp.kassa.date_prov">DateProv</th>
            <th jhiTranslate="jhiApp.kassa.date_doc">DateDoc</th>
            <th jhiTranslate="jhiApp.kassa.num_doc">NumDoc</th>
            <th jhiTranslate="jhiApp.kassa.acc_db">AccDb</th>
            <th jhiTranslate="jhiApp.kassa.bank_db">BankDb</th>
            <th jhiTranslate="jhiApp.kassa.name_db">NameDb</th>
            <th jhiTranslate="jhiApp.kassa.acc_cr">AccCr</th>
            <th jhiTranslate="jhiApp.kassa.bank_cr">BankCr</th>
            <th jhiTranslate="jhiApp.kassa.name_cr">NameCr</th>
            <th jhiTranslate="jhiApp.kassa.currency">Currency</th>
            <th jhiTranslate="jhiApp.kassa.summa">Summa</th>
            <th jhiTranslate="jhiApp.kassa.summa_eq">SummaEq</th>
            <th jhiTranslate="jhiApp.kassa.purpose">Purpose</th>
            <th jhiTranslate="jhiApp.kassa.inn_db">InnDb</th>
            <th jhiTranslate="jhiApp.kassa.inn_cr">InnCr</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody *ngFor="let array of kassas">

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

in css

```
thead th {
position: sticky;
top: 0;
background-color: lightskyblue;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code be usefull

```css
thead th{
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}

thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.table-responsive {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <h1>Table</h1>
 <div class="table-responsive " style="width: 100%; height: 670px;">
    <!--<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">-->
    <table class="table table-hover info">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <!--<th jhiTranslate="jhiApp.kassa.date_enter">DateEnter</th>-->
            <th jhiTranslate="jhiApp.kassa.date_prov">DateProv</th>
            <th jhiTranslate="jhiApp.kassa.date_doc">DateDoc</th>
            <th jhiTranslate="jhiApp.kassa.num_doc">NumDoc</th>
            <th jhiTranslate="jhiApp.kassa.acc_db">AccDb</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>5</td>
           </tr>
          
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
   <p>lorem</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling `<tbody>` with fixed `<thead>` (well in your case, sticky `<thead>`) is a log discussed thread.

See the answers to [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266262/position-sticky-on-thead), especially this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266262/position-sticky-on-thead/43895506#43895506)

If that does not help,  see this [sticky implementation here](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/) and try not to use table but other html tags like for instance plain `<div>`s and style accordingly. I've seen the example uses description list tags.

I've had a similar situation (with the need for fixed `<thead>`) so I ended up with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53520969/5669268) approach. My case implied the material lib but it does not matter the approach of scrolling the "table" body is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my new Angular sticky library. I created it because I missed such functionality and no solutions worked for me. https://ngx-sticky-copy.netlify.app/ It is easy, you only apply *scStickyThead directive on tHead and you go.